# Animation script - No module named PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, maya

Hi I tried to use a animation script

free meshcache for maya

# this is the error that I have ( No module named PyQt4 # )

> Error: line 1: ImportError: file C:/Users/Lav/Documents/maya/2016/scripts/meshCache_script.py line 5: No module named PyQt4 `

#I am using maya 2016 with service pack in window 7 64 bit

Is it possible to change this script, so that everybody can use without dealing with pyqt4 install or others.

If I could use this script, I really appreciate for you.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specific case of that script it should be as easy as replacing:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sip
```

with:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import shiboken
```

and then, on `line 32`, replacing:

```
return sip.wrapinstance(long(controlPoniter), QtCore.QObject)
```

with:

```
return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(controlPoniter), QtGui.QWidget)
```

Then follow the instructions [here](https://www.highend3d.com/maya/plugin/free-meshcache-for-maya) (where I assume you got the script) and it should work.

What I suggested is what I believe the author was doing with the `meshCache_script_2016.py` file he mentions, in the page linked above. I downloaded the zipped file from there but couldn't find `meshCache_script_2016.py` in there, so you might want to ask the author if he omitted it on purpose (in case he realised that other parts of his script and/or plugin would break in Maya 2016, anyway).

Comment: You are awe~~~~some man and genius, you are my hero!!!!!!!!!  thank you guys.                                     I really appreciate for your help  :)

Comment: sorry, when I use this script, there is a problem,,,                                               error is  //                                                                                                        # Error: AttributeError: file <maya console> line 37: 'module' object has no attribute 'wrapinstance'    //                                                                             after chaning these line it works but such error happens,    do you know how can it works?   thank you very much.  I also ask to the author to upload the 2016 version.

Comment: sorry, I mistyped the shiboken line (just edited the answer to fix that). Could you try now, making sure you have `shiboken.wrapInstance` (with capital `I`), instead of `shiboken.wrapinstance` as I had written before? Hopefully it is just that. Also, not sure why you get the error on line `37` while I have that call on line `32`. Did you change/add anything else in the script?

Comment: yes, after changing this, it works but other issue happen, // line 50: 'PySide.QtCore.QObject' object has no attribute 'layout',,, I am sorry about asking continually, if you are possible let me know, but I don't want bother you, anyhow thank you very much,  if we can converse immediately it will be good though , now I  am live in USA time, thank you very much

Comment: mmm, I feel a bit embarassed as I should have tested the script before answering but I didn't have time to see how it's supposed to work, nor I have now. Sorry :/ If you can, try this: `return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(controlPoniter), QtGui.QWidget)` instead of what I posted in the answer (still on line `32`). I'll update the answer only when it works...

Comment: Thank you very much, It works, I really really appreciate for your help, you are my hero  ,thank you so much , and  blessing you :):)

Comment: I was just trying to help, no need to disturb heroes :D I'm glad it worked in the end, I'm going to update the answer now. After you checked that everything else works as expected, maybe you could mark the answer as accepted? Best of luck with your work, cheers